# label in xsl - change the text

Tags: xslt

if i want that some value from the xml insert into the text area in the label in the xsl. how can i do that?

for example if i want that the ID attribute inser into the label foreach ID.

Comment: Provide XML before and desired after examples will help us answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kind of vague, but here's my guess as to what you want.

```
<label><xsl:value-of select="/foo/bar/"/></label>
```

Comment: it doesn't work.
i have tag name:"theAdv"
this tag include html code
i want display this html. i think i should put tjis in label,
but it doesn't work.